# Ripple geolocation settings being ignored by Cordova application

Tags: cordova, gps, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and I've installed the Visual Studio for Cordova add-on (version 0.3.22015.1).

I have created an Angular based app based on the [Ionic SideMenu Starter Template for Cordova](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Ionic-SideMenu-Starter-8e905eb5) example. I have included the Cordova geolocation plugin in the config.xml file.

Within this example I am obtaining the device's location using the following code:

```
$scope.showPosition = function (position) {
 // ...
}

$scope.getLocation = function () {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition, $scope.showError);
 }
 else {
  $scope.error = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }
}
```

When this code is executed I'm expecting the position object passed to the showPosition callback to have the mock geolocation values specified in the Ripple emulator. However I don't get these mock values, I get my actual position.

How can I get my code to use the mock values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this was a bug with Ripple itself. The good news is a fix was just released on Wednesday. https://github.com/apache/incubator-ripple/blob/master/doc/CHANGELOG.md

You can patch Ripple in VS 2013 by opening the command command prompt and typing:

```
cd %appdata%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda
npm install ripple-emulator@0.9.29 --save
```

For VS 2015:

```
cd %appdata%\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
npm install ripple-emulator@0.9.29 --save
```

You will need to do this again if you clear the Cordova Cache.

Comment: Hi Chuck. I ran the patch successfully. However when I now run my app in VS 2013, instead of successfully uploading the app to my Android device I get the error "Error : DEP10201 : Failed to deploy to device, no devices found." which is thrown from here "\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126". Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: It turns out that I needed to reinstall the ADB USB driver for my phone, which is most likely a problem nit related to updating ripple. For those that are in a similar situation a nice guide on updating the ADB driver can be found here http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/2/