# Cordova Geolocation plugin in ripple

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I added cordova-plugin-geolocation to my cordova app in VS 2015. For some reason Ripple seems not to support it. I get this error:

Geolocation.getPermission
We seem to be missing some stuff :(

Does this meas that Ripple did not implemented this?

Comment: Ripple is okay for testing some basic functions. For testing geolocations you should use something like genymotion and/or the simulators which are bundled with Xcode. And you should test it on real devices, because the simulators just push some values to your software and this is not a real world scenario.

Comment: Agreed, i tried to answer a similar question with some more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646749/cordova-plugin-listpicker-error-on-ripple-emulator/34652788#34652788)

Comment: I have the same issue here. I've found this link that recommends to update Ripple emulator to a later version that has been fixed this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30266829/4730201

Comment: This still doesn't work, Ripple 0.9.32.

Comment: I ended up changing geolocation plugin that when it uses ripple to use native browser location: https://github.com/radud/cordova-plugin-geolocation/commit/a997681dec945480177c2ada4aa633db46f2e5be

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the Cordova Cache and the error went away for me and worked fine with RIPPLE emulator.

Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Cordova Tools -> Clear Cordova Cache

Take a bit to reload all the stuff for your next run, but it worked for me.